# Writing a plugin which needs to upload files

Tags: plugin-development

I am quite new to Wordpress development, and am writing a plugin which needs to have an option of uploading a spreadsheet, which the plugin will then work with and process data as appropriate.

This is for front end users, not in the admin area.

What is the best practice? Should I code an upload myself, or integrate another plugin, which my plugin calls and is dependent on? If the latter, any suggestions of a plugin????

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be part of the solution you're looking for: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter

How familiar are you with web-forms in php & file-uploads in general?

Here's a prebuilt plugin solution for frontend uploads: https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/

& here's a tutorial which looks to be along the lines of what you're describing: https://www.inkthemes.com/code-to-integrate-wordpress-media-uploader-in-plugintheme/